# How do I get my excel formulas to work with this error?

Tags: excel

My forumlas are suddenly not working I get this error every time.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wYhY9.png)

Comment: can you post your formulas? otherwise its hard to tell whats wront with them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be a formula: `=1+1`

If you don't want it to be a formula: `'=1+1`

If the error keeps showing, try [these](https://windowsreport.com/problem-formula-excel/) steps.

Comment: That's what happened. I changed my date and time to match where I am which is Denmark. ugh. Thanks so much.

Comment: So my next question is how do I change the date without messing with how I enter formulas in excel?

Comment: You can change the language, but the list separator needs to be a comma. Control Panel -> Date and Time -> Formats -> Additional Settings -> Numbers -> Set the list separator to a comma

Comment: Hi all. Thanks for the answers. It was the date format on my computer. I changed it and it messed with the way I enter my formulas. Or the way excel looked at them anyway. So that’s annoying but I’ll just leave the date format and deal with it.